# In mpdf to Output a pdf file to a Browser

Tags: mpdf

I am trying to view the pdf file created using mpdf.
On using the command as

```
$pdf = $mpdf->Output('mep.pdf','I');
```

the pdf gets downloaded rather.
Although, I: send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if available. The name given by filename is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.

I would like to view the pdf in the browser and depending on the user choice to download it, print it or just view it and exit.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: I see you use the variable $pdf to store $mpdf->Output('mep.pdf','I');. Could it be because of this. Did you try directly: $mpdf->Output('mep.pdf','I'); ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser whether it can and will display PDF files inline. But to help it a little you should at least tell the browser that it's a PDF file. You can do this by sending a content-type header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

This line should be executed before sending the PDF contents.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply..
I do have my set of headers here...

`if (headers_sent())
                        $this->Error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send PDF file');

                        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

                        header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
                        header('Pragma: public');

                        header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');

                        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');`

Comment: and
`header('Content-Type: application/force-download');

                        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

                        header('Content-Type: application/download');

                        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

                        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');`

Comment: You overwrite the Content-Type a couple of times. This seems like a mess. You only need a couple of headers.

Comment: And even if you want multiple times the same header, you need to specify `false` as the second parameter in header, to prevent overwriting the previous one.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this. May be it will help you.

include file:

include_once './mpdf/mpdf.php';

create object of mpdf:

$pdf =new mPDF("","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3);

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Text which you want in PDF file');

> $pdf->Output('filename.pdf','I');

Still not able to view file:

define content type of header

> header('Content-Type: application/pdf',charset=utf-8');